# Large dataset - ANN

Tags: scikit-learn, neural-network, classification

I am trying to classify around 400K data with 13 attributes. I have used python sklearn's SVM package, but it didn't work, and then I learned that SVM's are not suitable for large dataset classification. Then I used the (sklearn) ANN using the following MLPClassifier:

```
MLPClassifier(solver='adam', alpha=1e-5, random_state=1,activation='relu', max_iter=500)
```

and trained the system using 200K samples, and tested the model on the remaining ones. The classification worked well. However, my concern is that the system is over trained or overfit. Can you please guide me on the number of hidden layers and node sizes to make sure that there is no overfit? (I have learned that the default implementation has 100 hidden neurons. Is it ok to use the default implementation as is?)

Answer (score 0):

To know if your are overfitting you have to compute:

- Training set accuracy
- Test set accuracy

Once you have calculated this scores, compare it. **If training set score is much better than your test set score, then you are overfitting**. This means that your model is "memorizing" your data, instead of learning from it to make future predictions.

If you are overfitting with Neuronal Networks you probably have to reduce the number of layers and reduce the number of neurons per layer. **There isn't any strict rule that says the number of layer or neurons you need depending on you dataset size**. Every dataset can behaves completely different with the same dataset size.

So, to conclude, if you are overfitting, you would have to evaluate your model accuracy using different parameters of layers and number of neurons, and, then, observe with which values you obtain the best results. There are some methods you can use to find the best parameters, is like `gridsearchCV`.

Comment: thanks @alex-serra-marrugat! I have checked it and they both give similar scores. maybe it is the case since I have a huge dataset compared to the number of features?

Comment: Glad my answer helps you. About what you mention, then, you are not overfitting. So your model is completely correct. Having less number makes having overfitting more difficult, so, if you have small number of features is good, this is not a problem for you.

Comment: thanks @alex-serra-marrugat! is it a problem if they both give 1 as F1 scores, since the ANN correctly classified them, no FP or FN.

Comment: It seems strange, maybe your problem is easy, I mean, it's easy to classify samples. You also have to think that ANN is a super powerful tool. Try another model like Random Forest, and check which F1 score. But, you don't have over fit, because you obtain also a good result with test data (that the model haven't seen before).